# Add Background Image to UITableView programmatically

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a background image to a table view. I am using Xcode and swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .backgroundView property on your tableview object and set it with whatever UIImageView you want. [UITableView Apple Reference Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView)

`tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "something.png"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add image like this way also:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "your_image_name")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add imageView to background layer and set what ever image to that image view .And set table view background color & cell color to **clear**.